# Pangram sentence

Tags: english, pangram

Create a pangram sentence by replacing the 26 dots with the
26 letters of the alphabet (different dots, different letters):

```
       ...  .A..  ..C..  .U..K  .H..  ...ES  .U..  O.E.  ..EM
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> big  lAzy  duCks  qUacK  wHen  foxES  jUmp  OvEr  thEM

The first place my mind goes when someone says "pangram" is to those jumping foxes. The letters given in *quack*, *jump*, and *over* were especially helpful getting this one started.